# Is having an element "$i$" such that multiplicativeInverse=additiveInverse a defining characteristic of algebraically closed Fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory

I've been looking for a simple definition of algebraically closed Fields that doesn't involve polynomials and roots.

I've noticed that, in the cases I know about (namely $\mathbb{C}$ and the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$), a defining characteristic is the presence of the imaginary unit $i$, defined as the number that satisfies $i^2=-1$. Since all complex numbers can be derived from $i$,  **is the existence of the imaginary unit $i$ all that a Field needs to be algebraically closed?**
And if it is not, could you provide a counterexample of a not-closed field having it?

As a side note, I believe that a more elegant definition of $i$ is: the number whose additive and multiplicative inverses are the same. Using my own notation, if my thesis is correct, the property of being algebraically closed would look like this:

$A$ is algebraically closed $\iff\exists i\in A:\overline{i_{\cdotp}}=\overline{i_{+}}$

Comment: I don't understand this question. In any algebraically closed field, there is an element satisfying $1/x = -x$, since that equation can be rearranged to form $-1 = x^2$. However, not all fields with a solution to that equation is algebraically closed.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of such a field? I explicitly asked for one in the question

Comment: The answer gives an example.

Comment: Also, from the first comment, your condition is equivalent to asking for a solution to the equation $x^2+1=0$, so not only does it not give a characterization, it also does involve roots of polynomials...

Answer (score 5):

No. The field $\mathbb Q(i)$ obtained by adjoining $i$ to the rationals is not algebraically closed.  You need all polynomials of degree $\ge 1$ over your field to have roots, not just $z^2+1$.

Comment: More generally, the field extension $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\supset\mathbb{Q}$ is not generated by *any* finite set of elements.

Comment: Or the field with five elements has $2$ satisfying $2^{-1} = -2$.

Comment: I get your point, but since we have adjoined $i$ to a field, we can use addition and multiplication to obtain every other number in $\mathbb{C}$, which is algebraically closed. So i don't feel like my question has been fully answered

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is countable and $\mathbb{C}$ is uncountable, so $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is not 
 $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @FrancescoCola how are you getting $\sqrt{2}$ for example?

Comment: @FrancescoCola Starting with $\mathbb{Q}$ results in a **very** different picture than starting with $\mathbb{R}$! $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is quite far from $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, since for example only the latter contains a cube root of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

For a prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, the field $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ (that means the integers mod $p$, which you may see also written as $\mathbf Z_p$ or $\mathbf F_p$) contains a solution to $a^2 = -1$, so this field has an "$i$" in it, but this field is extremely far from being algebraically closed: it has irreducible polynomials of every degree.

As a practical matter, (i) there is no simple definition of being algebraically closed in the style you are trying to find and (ii) all algebraically closed fields other than $\mathbf C$ and $\overline{\mathbf Q}$ are fairly abstract.

You asked about characterizations of a field $K$ being algebraically closed that don't mention polynomials or roots. One possibility is that the only field extension of $K$ that is of finite dimension over $K$ is $K$ itself.  Another is that if $L$ is a field strictly bigger than $K$ and $\alpha \in L - K$ then $K[\alpha] \not= K(\alpha)$.

Comment: I'm familiar with modular arithmetic and congruence, but the notation Z/pZ is new to me. What kind of field does it describe? What are its elements, its operations and thus its neutral elements? (Your response was overall very clear and much appreciated, thanks!!!)

Comment: I added other notations for that.  It means the integers mod $p$, so $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ (or $\mathbf Z_5$ or $\mathbf F_5$) is $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ with addition and multiplication done modulo $5$.  In this field, $2$ and $3$ satisfy the relations $-a = 1/a$ since they satisfy $a^2 = -1$ (note $-1 = 4$ when working modulo $5$).